# Basic GUI java program in Eclipse keeps crashing

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, user-interface, crash

I am trying to make a game and in said game, there are 21 sticks and each person takes turns taking 1-4 sticks until there are no sticks left, if you cant take anymore sticks you lose. I have successfully made this program in eclipse but now I want to add GUI to it so I have to change the code. This code isn't complete but it crashes whenever I press the Go button which is my actionListener. I would type in a number to the text field, press go and it will just crash. How can I fix this?

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

import javax.swing.*;

public class Sticks extends JFrame {

JButton Go;
JTextField tf1, tf2;
static JTextField sttf;
JLabel startTake;
static JLabel errorTake;
JLabel uTake;
JLabel compTake;

public Sticks() {
    setLayout(new GridLayout(5, 2, 5, 5));

    startTake = new JLabel("How many sticks do you want to take? (1-4)");
    add(startTake);

    sttf = new JTextField();
    add(sttf);

    errorTake = new JLabel("Hello");
    add(errorTake);

    Go = new JButton("Go");
    add(Go);

    uTake = new JLabel("");
    add(uTake);

    compTake = new JLabel("");
    add(compTake);

    // tf1 = new JTextField();
    // add(tf1);

    // TakeP = new JLabel("One stick taken");
    // add(TakeP);

    event e = new event();
    Go.addActionListener(e);
}

public static class event implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        int numSticks = 21;
        int numToTake = 0;
        int randomNum = 0;

        while (numSticks > 0) {
            try {
                int num = (int) (Double.parseDouble(sttf.getText()));
                int NumSticks = numSticks - num;

                    errorTake.setText("There are: " + numSticks + " left");

                    Robot Rob = new Robot();
                    numToTake = (int)Math.random() * 4 + 1;
                    errorTake.setText("There are: " + numSticks + " left");
                }
             catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();;errorTake.setText("There is a problem");
            }
        }
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Sticks gui = new Sticks();
    gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    gui.setVisible(true);
    gui.setSize(600, 200);

    gui.setTitle("Nice Game");
}
}
```

Comment: Change `catch (Exception exx) { errorTake.setText("Numbers only!");` to `catch (Exception exx) { exx.printStackTrace(); errorTake.setText("Numbers only!");`  Then copy/paste exception output.

Comment: I am not getting a stackTrace

Answer (score 0):

Everytime you click the "Go" button, your actionPerformed fires, and it doesn't wait for user input at all. This is your problem line.

```
public static class event implements ActionListener {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //...
                int num = (int) (Double.parseDouble(sttf.getText()));
        //...
    }
}
```

sttf.getText() always returns "" because sttf is empty, the program doesn't wait for user input unlike Scanner(System.in).

Makes sense that you don't get any Exceptions because it just runs and finishes the game without giving the user enough time to input anything. Are you sure the console doesn't print "Numbers only!", though? Because I've never tried to parse an empty String before.

---

Okay I've been reading this all wrong, sorry.

Your actionListener generates a new game everytime you click it, because you set your numSticks to 21 at each click. Looking forward, I don't think that's a good idea unless you want to take the same amount of sticks the whole way until the game ends. Same thing stands. If you input a value in sttf, the program won't wait for you to change it because it'd keep using that value until your while loop ends.

Comment: You see I don't get anything thrown. When I launch the program, the java window I made comes up and I enter in a value into the text field and press go and it just stops working.

Comment: By "stops working", do you mean it freezes? Because that most likely means you're in an infinite loop.

Comment: I think you are right it might be an infinite loop, Iv have updated my code above but am still getting the same problem. No StackTraces are being printed, what now?